# c++ pointers & Arrays

Tags: c++, pointers, arduino

I am really at my wits end with trying to get pointers to work on c++. I have searched so many questions, but I just cant understand these things.

I am trying to do the equivalent of this python code in c++ :

```
    class Node:

    def __init__(self,isBase,channelList):
        self.isBase = isBase
        self.channelList = channelList

    def getChannelList(self):
        return self.channelList

    def isBase(self):
        return self.isBase
```

Channel list is the difficult bit. It is an array of integers.
I know that this will be passed as a pointer to my class declaration. I want to be able to store this in a class variable, and  be able to get and set it on command.

The C++ Code is as follows:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Node.h"
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>

int *_channelList;
Node::Node(boolean isBase, int *channelList)
{
    _isBase = isBase;
    int i=0;
    while(channelList[i]!='\0'){
        _channelList[i] = channelList[i];
        i++;
    }
    _channelList[i+1] = '\0';
    }

boolean Node::isBase(){
     return _isBase;
}

int* Node::getChannelList(){
    return _channelList;
}
```

Comment: Don't pass arrays as pointers. Simple as that.

Comment: If you need a fixed-size array of integers, use std::array<int>. If you need the size to be dynamic, use std::vector<int>. Don't bother with pointers; pass them by (const) refererence.

Comment: Perhaps you should post your C++ code so we can see what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: Doesn't an array automatically decay to a pointer when a function parameter?

Comment: @ColinBasnett, the code is up now

Comment: `_channelList` is declared in a global scope, is this what you want? It seems more like you want each node to have it's own channel list.

Comment: Also, unless you have some code somewhere else `_channelList` doesn't have any memory it points to - it's uninitialized. So, when you're writing to it in the Node constructor, you're writing to invalid memory.

Comment: You stop copying over channelList when you reach an entry that is equal to the null character.  This is unusual for integer arrays, to say the least.  Are you sure your global channelList is null-terminated? ...You really need to post an MCVE.

Comment: @ZiyadYehia Yes, arrays decay to pointers, but that doesn't mean an `int*` can be used as an array just like that.  If `_channelList` isn't pointing to an actual array, you may encounter problems.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `channelList` is null-terminated, and that `_channelList` is supposed to be a class member, you could try this:

```
#include <algorithm> // For std::copy().

// ...

template<size_t N> Node::Node(bool isBase, const int (&channelList)[N]) : _isBase(isBase)
{
    std::copy(std::begin(channelList), std::end(channelList), std::begin(_channelList));
}
```

Unless I'm missing something, that should take a C-style int array of any size, and copy it into `_channelList`.  If the passed array is larger than `_channelList`, it may cause issues.  If possible, you would be better off using a `std::array` if the size is predetermined, or a `std::vector` if it isn't.

---

If the size is fixed:

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>  // For std::copy() and std::fill().

const size_t _sz = [whatever];
// Simple way of setting size, but not the best.  See below.

class Node
{
    bool _isBase;
    std::array<int, _sz> _channelList;

    public:
        Node(bool isBase, const int (&channelList)[_sz]);
        Node(bool isBase, const std::array<int, _sz>& channelList);
        // ...
};

/* Alternatively, you can code the size into the class as a magic number (not a good idea),
 * or better yet, make it a template parameter for the class:
 *     template<size_t _sz> class Node
 *     {
 *         bool _isBase;
 *         std::array<int, _sz> _channelList;
 *
 *         public:
 *             Node(/ * parameters * /);
 *
 *             template<size_t N>
 *             Node(/ * parameters * /);
 *         // ...
 *     };
 * When using the class, you would declare an instance as "Node<SIZE>", where "SIZE" is the
 * desired size.
 *
 * Note that if you make the size a template parameter, and define the member functions
 * outside of the class' definition, you have to put the same template at the start of each
 * member function:
 *     template<size_t _sz> Node<_sz>::Node(/ * parameters * /)
 *     {
 *         // ...
 *     }
 * This also applies to templated member functions, which will have two sets of template
 * parameters.
 *     template<size_t _sz> template<size_t N> Node<_sz>::Node(/ * parameters * /)
 *     {
 *         // ...
 *     }
 */

// Constructor initialising from C array, if you need to work with preexisting code.
Node::Node(bool isBase, const int (&channelList)[_sz]) : _isBase(isBase)
{
    std::copy(std::begin(channelList), std::end(channelList), std::begin(_channelList));
}

// Constructor using std::array.
Node::Node(bool isBase, const std::array<int, _sz>& channelList)
  : _isBase(isBase), _channelList(channelList)
{
    // Initialisation list handles everything.
}

// Note, however, that this will cause issues if the size of channelList doesn't
// necessarily match the size of _channelList.  To solve this, we can change Node as
// follows:
// (Note that delegation requires a C++11-compatible compiler.)

#include <type_traits>  // For std::integral_constant, std::true_type, and std::false_type.

class Node {
    bool _isBase;
    std::array<int, _sz> _channelList;

    // Actual constructors (C-style array):
    template<size_t N>
    Node(std::true_type x, bool isBase, const int (&channelList)[N]);

    template<size_t N>
    Node(std::false_type x, bool isBase, const int (&channelList)[N]);

    // Actual constructors (std::array):
    template<size_t N>
    Node(std::true_type x, bool isBase, const std::array<int, N>& channelList);

    template<size_t N>
    Node(std::false_type x, bool isBase, const std::array<int, N>& channelList);

    public:
        // Public constructors, delegate to one of the actual constructors.
        // C-style array:
        template<size_t N>
        Node(bool isBase, const int (&channelList)[N]);

        // std::array:
        template<size_t N>
        Node(bool isBase, const std::array<int, N>& channelList);

        // ...
};

/* Now, these constructors are easy enough to make.
 * I'll provide an example using C-style arrays.  To make versions that take a
 * std::array instead, change the parameter:
 *     const int (&channelList)[N]
 * to:
 *     const std::array<int, N>& channelList
 * The constructors should work properly with either kind of array.
 */

// Check if passed array is smaller than or equal to _sz, or if it's larger..
template<size_t N> Node::Node(bool isBase, const int (&channelList)[N])
  : Node(std::integral_constant<bool, N <= _sz>{}, isBase, channelList) { }

// N is smaller than or equal to _sz.
template<size_t N> Node::Node(std::true_type x, bool isBase, const int (&channelList)[N])
  : _isBase(isBase)
{
    // Copy channelList into _channelList.
    std::copy(std::begin(channelList), std::end(channelList), std::begin(_channelList));
    // Fill empty space at the end of _channelList.
    std::fill(&(_channelList[N]), std::end(_channelList), '\0');
}

// N is larger than _sz.
template<size_t N> Node::Node(std::false_type x, bool isBase, const int (&channelList)[N])
{
    // Handle appropriately.
}
```

This should allow you to get the functionality you want.  [Note that you can also use the above delegation, `true_type`, and `false_type` constructors to fill C-style arrays as well as `std::array`s, if you need to use them.]

---

If the size isn't fixed:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class Node {
    bool _isBase;
    std::vector<int> _channelList;

    public:
        template<size_t N>
        Node(bool isBase, const int (&channelList)[N]);

    // ...
};

template<size_t N> Node::Node(bool isBase, const int (&channelList)[N]) : _isBase(isBase)
{
    _channelList.assign(std::begin(channelList), std::end(channelList));
}

// You can also define a constructor that takes a std::array<int, N>, if you
// so desire.  Again, the only change needed is the parameter itself.
```

As a vector's length can be changed at runtime, we can use `vector::assign` to allocate space and store the entirety of `channelList`.

---

Regardless of whether `_channelList` is stored as a C array, `std::array`, or `std::vector`, it's relatively easy to define getters and setters.

Getter (entire thing):

```
// All of the following use this class definition, with comments identifying which
// functions use which parts.
// Note that the trailing "const" in each getter signature indicates that the function
// cannot be used to modify the instance.  It's optional, but useful to include.
class Node {
    // Return C array (either way).
    int _channelListC[_sz];
    // Return std::array.
    std::array<int, _sz> _channelListSArr;
    // Return std::vector.
    std::vector<int> _channelListSVec;

    // Return C array the readable way.
    typedef int _channelListC_t[_sz];
    // C++11 alternative typedef:
    using _channelListC_t = decltype(_channelList);
    // The C++11 version is safer, as "decltype(_channelList)" won't break if you change
    // _channelList's implementation.
    // If you need to return the entire array, it may be a good idea to make this a public
    // typedef, so it's easier & safer to declare a variable you can return it to.

    public:
        // Return C array the ugly way.
        const int (&getChannelListCUgly() const)[_sz];

        // Return C array the readable way.
        const _channelListC_t& getChannelListCReadable() const;

        // Return C array the readable C++11 way.
        auto getChannelListCReadableCPP11() const -> const int(&)[_sz];

        // Return std::array.
        const std::array<int, _sz>& getChannelListSArr() const;

        // Return std::vector.
        const std::vector<int>& getChannelListSVec() const;
};

// Return C array:
/* Note that you can't return an array from a function.  However, you can return a pointer
 * or reference to an array, depending on whether you use * or & in the signature.
 */
// The ugly way:
const int (&Node::getChannelListCUgly() const)[_sz]
{
    return _channelList;
}

// The readable way:
const Node::_channelListC_t& Node::getChannelListCReadable() const
{
    return _channelList;
}

// The new readable way, as of C++11:
auto getChannelListCReadableCPP11() const -> const int(&)[_sz]
{
    return _channelList;
}

// Return std::array:
const std::array<int, _sz>& Node::getChannelListSArr() const
{
    return _channelList;
}

// Return std:;vector:
const std::vector<int>& getChannelListSVec() const
{
    return _channelList;
}
```

Note that to my knowledge, a C-style array returned in this manner must be stored in a reference variable.

```
Node::_channelListC_t& arr = nodeInstance.getChannelListCUgly();
```

Getter (single element):

```
// C array or std::array:
int Node::getChannelListArrElement(int index) const
{
    if (index < _sz)
    {
        // index is valid, return element.
        return _channelList[index];
    }
    else
    {
        // index >= _sz, and is invalid.
        // Handle accordingly.
    }
}

// std::vector:
int Node::getChannelListVecElement(int index) const
{
    if (index < _channelList.size())
    {
        // index is valid.
        return _channelList[index];
    }
    else
    {
        // index is invalid.
        // Handle accordingly.
    }
}
```

You can define a setter for the entire thing using the constructors above.  I would suggest using `std::fill()` to erase the contents of `_channelList` first, then copying the new array into `_channelList`.  You can define a setter for single elements using the single-element getter as a basis.

Setter (entire thing):

```
// Array (either type):
//   "CHANNEL_LIST_TYPE[N] channelList" is either "const int (&channelList)[N]" or
//   "std::array<int, N>& channelList".  Remember to replace it with the correct one in the
//   actual code.

// Public function.
template<size_t N>
void Node::setChannelListArr(CHANNEL_LIST_TYPE[N] channelList)
{
    setChannelListArr(std::integral_constant<bool, N <= _sz>{}, channelList);
}

// Private function, N <= _sz.
template<size_t N>
void Node::setChannelListArr(std::true_type x, CHANNEL_LIST_TYPE[N] channelList)
{
    std::fill(std::begin(_channelList), std::end(_channelList), '\0');
    std::copy(std::begin(channelList), std::end(channelList), std::begin(_channelList));
}

// Private function, N > _sz.
template<size_t N>
void Node::setChannelListArr(std::false_type x, CHANNEL_LIST_TYPE[N] channelList)
{
    // channelList is too large.  Handle appropriately.
}


// std::vector:
//   "CHANNEL_LIST_TYPE[N]" is used as above, and should be replaced in your actual code.
//   Also note that you can easily modify this function to accept another vector, by
//   removing the template, making the parameter "const std::vector<int>& channelList", and
//   using "channelList.size()" in place of "N" when calling resize().
template<size_t N>
void Node::setChannelListVec(CHANNEL_LIST_TYPE[N] channelList)
{
    _channelList.resize(N); // Resize _channelList to have N elements.
    std::fill(std::begin(_channelList), std::end(_channelList), '\0');
    std::copy(std::begin(channelList), std::end(channelList), std::begin(_channelList));
}
```

Setter (single element):

```
// Array (either type):
void Node::setChannelListArrElement(int index, int value)
{
    if (index < _sz)
    {
        _channelList[index] = value;
    }
    else
    {
        // index is invalid.  Handle accordingly.
    }
}

// std::vector:
void Node::setChannelListVecElement(int index, int value)
{
    if (index < _channelList.size())
    {
        _channelList[index] = value;
    }
    else
    {
        // index is invalid.  Handle accordingly.
    }
}

// Alternative std::vector setter:
void Node::setChannelListVecElement2(int index, int value)
{
    if (index >= _channelList.size())
    {
        // index is out of bounds.  Resize vector to fit it.
        _channelList.resize(index + 1, '\0');
    }

    // Modify element.
    _channelList[index] = value;
}
```

---

Note that this answer assumes that `channelList` is null-terminated, as it appears to be.  If `channelList` isn't null-terminated, but you want to stop filling `_channelList` at the first null element, then you'll have to do a bit more work, likely using your `while` loop.

---

You can find working examples of most of the above [here](http://ideone.com/liO6pN).  It's a bit of a mess, since it's just a quick program I used to test various things while typing up this answer.

---

[My apologies for any typoes and/or errors I may have missed.  I believe I caught them, but there may still be some there.]

[Edit: Added a note about using fixed-size template constructors with C arrays.  Added the C++11 trailing return type way of returning a reference to an array.  Added a simple, working example.]
[Edit: Added an additional single-element setter for a vector.]

Comment: Note that `std::array` has a member function `size()`, as well; since the size is known, and stored as a constant or template parameter, I used it directly for consistency.  Also note that both `array` and `vector` have member functions `begin()` and `end()`, such that `array_or_vector.begin()` is equivalent to `begin(array_or_vector)`, and `array_or_vector.end()` is equivalent to `end(array_or_vector)`.  Again, I went with the latter for consistency.

Answer (score 1):

Justin Time's answer is the correct way to implement this in C++ (using arrays and vectors natively handled by C++)

I just have to add this solution, which is the correct way to implement what you tried to do in C (i.e. using char arrays).

There are two problems in your code

1. `_channelList` is NOT tied to the `Node` object, but is a somewhat static member.
2. `_channelList` is never allocated, so it points to nothing.
3. not a real problem, but usually `'\0'` is the string terminator. Ok, it maps to `0`, but you should just use a `0` here

There are two solutions here. The first one is to give `_channelList` a fixed MAXIMUM size (maximum means that if the passed `channelList` is shorter you will get a shorter list, ok, but the allocated memory will still be the maximum one).

```
// File Node.h
#define MAXIMUM_CHANNELS    10
class Node {
    public:
        Node(boolean isBase, int *channelList);
        boolean isBase();
        int* getChannelList();

    private:
        int _channelList[MAXIMUM_CHANNELS + 1]; // Last one is the terminator
};

// File Node.cpp
include "Arduino.h"
#include "Node.h"
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>

Node::Node(boolean isBase, int *channelList)
{
    _isBase = isBase;
    int channelListLength;
    // Get channel list lenght
    for (channelListLength = 0; channelList[channelListLength] != 0; channelListLength++);

    if (channelListLength > MAXIMUM_CHANNELS)
        channelListLength = MAXIMUM_CHANNELS;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < channelListLength; i++)
        _channelList[i] = channelList[i];
    _channelList[channelListLength] = 0; // Enforce the last one to be a 0
}

boolean Node::isBase(){
    return _isBase;
}

int* Node::getChannelList(){
    return _channelList;
}
```

The second method dynamically allocates the memory for the array. You should, however, dispose it when you are done with the object (in the destructor). This means that if you create the `Node` variable you are ok (for instance, `Node mynode;`). If, however, you dynamically allocate it (with `Node *p_mynode = new Node();` you will need to call a `delete` on it when you are done.

```
// File Node.h
class Node {
    public:
        Node(boolean isBase, int *channelList);
        ~Node(); // destructor (called at object destruction)
        boolean isBase();
        int* getChannelList();

    private:
        int *_channelList;
};

// File Node.cpp
include "Arduino.h"
#include "Node.h"
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>

Node::Node(boolean isBase, int *channelList)
{
    _isBase = isBase;
    int channelListLength;
    // Get channel list lenght
    for (channelListLength = 0; channelList[channelListLength] != 0; channelListLength++);

    _channelList = (int*)malloc((channelListLength+1)*sizeof(int));
    if (_channelList != NULL)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i <= channelListLength; i++)
            _channelList[i] = channelList[i];
        // No need to enforce the last one to be a 0
    }
}

~Node()
{
    free(_channelList);
}

boolean Node::isBase(){
    return _isBase;
}

int* Node::getChannelList(){
    return _channelList;
}
```

Note, however, that if the `malloc` fails you will have a `NULL` pointer. In theory it should not fail, unless you run out of ram...

Just one more thing. Using a 0-terminated int array is not a good idea, because if you have something like this `{ 15, 3, 0, 5, 10 }` and then the terminator you will just get the first two numbers. It would be MUCH better to explicitely tell the array size (and save it in the object)

```
// File Node.h
class Node {
    [...]
    private:
        int *_channelList;
        int _channelListLength;
};

// File Node.cpp
Node::Node(boolean isBase, int *channelList, int channelListLength)
{
    _isBase = isBase;

    _channelListLength = channelListLength;
    _channelList = (int*)malloc((_channelListLength)*sizeof(int));
    if (_channelList != NULL)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i <= _channelListLength; i++)
            _channelList[i] = channelList[i];
    }
}

...

int Node::getChannelListLength(){
    return _channelListLength;
}
```